# Нужна ли запятая перед "и"?

Tags: пунктуация

Все наверняка замечали, что девочки любят играть с косметикой**, и** иногда так перегибают палку, что трудно определить их возраст.

Answer (score 1):

Все наверняка замечали, что девочки любят играть с косметикой и иногда так перегибают палку, что трудно определить их возраст.

-нет, не нужна,однородные сказуемые любят и перегибают палку соединены одиночным союзом.